# Add Excel file to HTML

Tags: html, excel, web, server

I created a web page locally on my computer and have added an Excel file to it and am able to access it through a link I have given in the page. But when I uploaded it to 000webhost.com, which is a free server, they have file structure like:

**root/public_html/**

where one can upload there HTML or CSS files.

When I tried to add the Excel file by uploading it to a sub-directory of public_html (i.e; public_html/doc/), then it's not getting opened from the link in my page. That link was working perfectly when I checked my page by running it locally, that is without FTP.

I have checked everything for that **a href** link option...its not working.
My piece of code:

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<title> PLACMENT CELL </title>
</HEAD>
 <body>

<div id="header">
<img src="top.jpg" width="1350" height="250">
</div>


<a href="http://gitplacment.comule.com/public_html/document/sheet001.htm"> click </a>


</body>
```

Is this wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Remove the `public_html/`. That's just a folder where you upload your actual site.

Comment: @Jeroen Bellemans so it ll b <a href="https://gitplacment.comule.com/document/sheet001.htm"> click </a>  ??

Comment: Is this path acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that should do it ;)

Comment: Its still not working. See my excel is in public_html/document and the index.html which is main page is in public_html/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://gitplacment.comule.com/public_html/document/sheet001.htm">
```

assuming that

gitplacment.comule.com is your domain

and your created a sub folder under the root of your site, inotherwords, the folder where your index.html file is, should have a subfolder called document. And under that folder should be a file named, sheet001.htm.

then

```
<a href="http://gitplacment.comule.com/document/sheet001.htm">
```

would open the file

but I tried that url and it didn't work, so perhaps you have an issue with your DNS, I tried without your subdomain and a webpage did load

```
http://comule.com/document/sheet001.htm
```

so I would check your DNS settings.